# Http interceptor doesn't log any information

Tags: angular, http, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have created a `CustomHttpInterceptor` which now I would like to just log some info, e.g:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('http intercpeotr', req, next)
    return next.handle(req);
  }
```

Of course I registred it in `providers` in `app.module` but nothing has been logged which I did some requests to the server.

My `angular` service looks like:

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
 getAllWithPaging(params: HttpParams){
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/withPaging?' + params.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to use the new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) (Angular 4.3) to do the request (imported from `@angular/common/http` instead of the old one imported from `@angular/http`.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAllWithPaging(params: HttpParams) {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.url + '/withPaging?' + params.toString());
  }
}
```

Refer to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http) for a detailed guide.